# How can I wait data from firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase

I need to wait data from firebase otherwise my app gonna crash because of nil value. I searched about that and watch some videos and look at other questions but I can't see any firebase example actually. How can I wait data from firebase? How can I use dispatch or semaphore and which one is more efficient?

Here my sample code:

```
        let uid = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
        let usrIndirimRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("indirimSayisi")
        usrIndirimRef.observe(.value) { (snap) in
            let userIndir = snap.value as! Int
            self.userIndirimSayisi = userIndir
            
            let usrIndirimTipiRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("indirimTipi")
             usrIndirimTipiRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                 
                if userIndir < 1 {
                    self.userIndirim = "0"
                    self.indirimKontrol = false 
             
                    self.tableView.reloadSections([1], with: .fade)
                    
                    
                }else{
                    self.userIndirim = snapshot.value! as! String
                    self.tableView.reloadSections([1], with: .fade)
                    
                    
                }
    
             }
        }
    
        
        toplamHesapTutari()
```

Here `toplamHesapTutari()` function execute before the data `userIndirim`. Its can be solve maybe hold execution for that function but I can't decide that is correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wait, never wait, run the code you need to run **inside** the completion handler

```
let uid = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
let usrIndirimRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("indirimSayisi")
usrIndirimRef.observe(.value) { (snap) in
    let userIndir = snap.value as! Int
    self.userIndirimSayisi = userIndir
    
    let usrIndirimTipiRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("indirimTipi")
     usrIndirimTipiRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
         
        if userIndir < 1 {
            self.userIndirim = "0"
            self.indirimKontrol = false 
     
            self.tableView.reloadSections([1], with: .fade)
            
            
        }else{
            self.userIndirim = snapshot.value! as! String
            self.tableView.reloadSections([1], with: .fade)
            
            
        }
        self.toplamHesapTutari()
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and I tried a lot of methods but still crash my app.

So I figure it out by putting the code that makes my app crash in a later function to spare some time for the essential data fully loads. I suggest you use try-catch and log to observe the error and prevent your app from keep crashing.

```
try {
     if ((snapshot.child("photo").value as? String)==null) {
           //if not load
     } else {
           //if load
     }
}catch(ex: Exception){}
```

Here is some reference for you:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html